# On calculating $\sigma(n^2) \pmod 4$ if $n$ is odd

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This will be my very first post in math.stackexchange, so please bear with me if I make any silly mistakes with my maths.

So, to proceed:  I am trying to calculate $\sigma(n^2) \mod 4$, given that $n$ is odd.

If I let $n = \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{r}{{p_i}^{{\alpha}_i}}$, then by considering the cases $p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $p_i \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ separately (and taking the exponents ${\alpha}_i$ into consideration as well), I am led to the final congruence relation:

$$\sigma(n^2) \equiv (-1)^c \pmod 4,$$

where $$c = \left|\left\{i|1 \le i \le r, p_i \equiv 1 \pmod4, 2 \nmid {\alpha}_i \right\}\right|.$$

My question now would be:  Is this as far as we could go with this congruence?  I mean, is there no further possible improvement to this congruence, as far as computing $\sigma(n^2) \pmod 4$ for odd $n$ is concerned?

Appreciate any of your replies/feedback on this.

Edit:  In response to Marvis's inquiry as to what sort of improvement I am looking at - I am trying to determine whether $\sigma(n^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \hspace{0.10in} XOR \hspace{0.10in} \sigma(n^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, given that I also know that $4 \nmid \left(\sigma(n) - 2\right)$.

Comment: In response to Marvis, I am hereby copying my comment to his answer here:  I am trying to determine if either $\sigma(n^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ XOR $\sigma(n^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, given that I also know that $4 \nmid \left(\sigma(n) - 2\right)$.

Comment: To clarify, so far I have:  $\sigma(n^2) \equiv (-1)^c \pmod 4$, where $c$ is the number of $i$'s such that $1 \le i \le r$, for prime(s) $p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and the corresponding exponent(s) $\alpha_i$ is/are odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p \equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $\sigma (p^{2 \alpha}) = 1 + p + p^2 + \cdots + p^{2 \alpha} \equiv (2 \alpha + 1)\pmod{4} \equiv (-1)^{\alpha}\pmod{4}$, since each term is $1 \pmod{4}$.

If $p \equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then $\sigma (p^{2 \alpha}) = 1 + p + p^2 + \cdots + p^{2 \alpha} \equiv 1\pmod{4}$, since $$1 + p + p^2 + \cdots + p^{2 \alpha} = 1 + p(1+p) + p^3(1+p) + p^5(1+p) + \cdots + p^{2 \alpha-1}(1+p)$$ and $1+p \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$.

Hence, $$\sigma(n^2) = \prod_{p_i-\text{primes of the form $4k+1$}} (-1)^{\alpha_i} \pmod{4}$$

Hence, if $\displaystyle \alpha = \sum_{i} \alpha_i$ where $\alpha_i$ is the highest power of prime $p_i$ of the form $4k+1$ dividing $n$, then $$\sigma(n^2) = (-1)^{\alpha} \pmod{4}$$

What sort of improvement are you looking at?

Comment: I am trying to determine if either $\sigma(n^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ XOR $\sigma(n^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, given that I also know that $4 \nmid \left(\sigma(n) - 2\right)$.

Comment: @ArnieDris $\alpha = 1 \implies (-1)^{\alpha} = -1$ and where did I say that $(p+1) \vert \sigma(p^{2 \alpha})$?

Comment: Oops sorry, got confused.  Yes you're right.  How do I delete these comments?  :(

Comment: There, found the delete button.  Sorry about that...

Comment: @ArnieDris No problem. I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: Hi Marvis, I double-checked my calculations.  You're spot right on considering only the residues of $p \mod 4$.  However, in light of my current considerations (i.e. trying to relate $\sigma(n^2)$ to $\sigma(n)$) I would have to do it my way and consider the exponent $\alpha$ too.  Thus, my clarification(s) in my comments above.

Comment: Hey Marvis, is that really $\sigma(n^2) \equiv (-1)^{\alpha} \pmod n$?  Shouldn't it be just $\sigma(n^2) \equiv (-1)^{\alpha} \pmod 4$?

Comment: @ArnieDris Yes $\pmod{4}$. It was a typo.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't realize that I forgot to accept your answer to my 'first' question here at MSE.  I would like you to know that I have already accepted it just now.